# Find the $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} xf'(x)$ using Taylor expansion

Tags: real-analysis

$Q)$ The second differentiable function $f : (1, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} xf(x) = 4$ and $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} xf''(x) = 3$

Find the $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} xf'(x)$

---

To solve this question I use the Taylor expansion (Here, $ x<t<x+1$)

Then, $f(x+1) = f(x) + f'(x) + {f''(t) \over 2}$ Then if we multiplying the $x$ on the both side

We get ${x \over {x+1}} \cdot {x+1} \cdot f(x+1) = xf(x) + xf'(x) + {f''(t) \over 2} \cdot t \cdot {x \over t}$

So becuase of the   $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} {x \over x+1} = 1$ and $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} {x \over t}=1$ by squeeze theorem for $ x<t<x+1$, Hence the answer is -$ 3 \over 2$

I tried different ways by $f(x) = f(x+1) - f'(x+1) + {f''(t) \over 2}$ (Again, $ x<t<x+1$ )

Similarly multiplying $x$ on the both side

We get  $x f(x) = x f(x+1) - xf'(x+1) + {f''(t) \over 2} \cdot t \cdot {x \over t}$, Hence the answer is ${3 \over 2}$

So my question is which answer is correct. I don't know which point I was wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

p.s.) The answer was - $3 \over 2$ as I remembered

Comment: If you try $f(x+2)$ you get yet another answer. Even funnier, do you for $f(x+1)=f(x)+f'(t)$, $t\in(x,x+1)$.

Comment: The problem is that if $f''(x)$ is equivalent to $\frac{3}{x}$ at infinity, then the first derivative for large $M$ and $x>M$ will be $$f'(x)\approx\text{const}+\int_M^x\frac{3}{x}\,dx$$ which is divergent, so $f'(x)\to \infty$. The same for $f(x)$, it goes to infinity even faster, and cannot have the same asymptotics $\frac1{x}$.

Comment: @A.Γ., then the question itself is nonsense, right?

Comment: It makes sense only if it is two different questions: a) for the first limit, and b) for the second one. Otherwise such functions does not exist. Using the [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) logic, $\forall f\in\emptyset$ you can claim everything, so both your answers are true in the sense :)

Comment: @A.Γ., beautiful....  :)